# sql query to find unique records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and need your help to achieve the below , I have tried using group and count functions but I am getting all the rows in the unique group which are duplicated.

Below is my source data.

```
CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration,Call_Plan
543,xxx-23,12,12,500
543,xxx-23,12,12,501
543,xxx-23,12,12,510
643,xxx-33,11,17,700
343,xxx-33,11,17,700
766,xxx-74,32,1,300
766,xxx-74,32,1,300
877,xxx-32,12,2,300
877,xxx-32,12,2,300
877,xxx-32,12,2,301
```

Please note :-the source has multiple combinations of unique records, so when I do the count the unique set is not appearing as count =1

example :- the below data in source have 60 records for each combination

```
877,xxx-32,12,2,300 -- 60 records
877,xxx-32,12,2,301 -- 60 records
```

I am trying to get the unique unique records, but the duplicate records are also getting in

Below are the rows which should come up in the unique group. i.e. there will be multiple call_Plans for the same combinations of CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration. I want to read records for which there is only  one call plan for each unique combination of CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration,

```
CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration,Call_Plan
643,xxx-33,11,17,700
343,xxx-33,11,17,700
766,xxx-74,32,1,300
```

Please advice on this.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Can you also please share the code, that you have tried till now ?, and just to give you a hint try the `COUNT` function in SQL

Answer (score 1):

To do more complex groupings you could also use a Common Table Expression/Derived Table along with windowed functions:

```
declare @t table(CDR_ID int,TelephoneNo nvarchar(20),Call_ID int,call_Duration int,Call_Plan int);
insert into @t values (543,'xxx-23',12,12,500),(543,'xxx-23',12,12,501),(543,'xxx-23',12,12,510),(643,'xxx-33',11,17,700),(343,'xxx-33',11,17,700),(766,'xxx-74',32,1,300),(766,'xxx-74',32,1,300),(877,'xxx-32',12,2,300),(877,'xxx-32',12,2,300),(877,'xxx-32',12,2,301);

with cte as
(
select CDR_ID
    ,TelephoneNo
    ,Call_ID
    ,call_Duration
    ,Call_Plan
    ,count(*) over (partition by CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration) as c
from (select distinct * from @t) a
)
select *
from cte
where c = 1;
```

Output:

```
+--------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---+
| CDR_ID | TelephoneNo | Call_ID | call_Duration | Call_Plan | c |
+--------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---+
|    343 | xxx-33      |      11 |            17 |       700 | 1 |
|    643 | xxx-33      |      11 |            17 |       700 | 1 |
|    766 | xxx-74      |      32 |             1 |       300 | 1 |
+--------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---+
```

Comment: In the question there are two rows where `cdr_id = 766` but only one of those two rows is in your code.

Comment: @SqlZim  That's what I get for answering the question before several edits are made...

Comment: You're right, I should have checked the edit history.  rextester demo http://rextester.com/TGXR99743 for your updated answer

Answer (score 1):

using `not exists()`

```
select distinct * 
from t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from t as i
  where i.cdr_id = t.cdr_id
    and i.telephoneno = t.telephoneno
    and i.call_id = t.call_id
    and i.call_duration = t.call_duration
    and i.call_plan <> t.call_plan
)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RRNNE20636

returns:

```
+--------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------+-----+
| cdr_id | TelephoneNo | Call_id | call_Duration | Call_Plan | cnt |
+--------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------+-----+
|    343 | xxx-33      |      11 |            17 |       700 |   1 |
|    643 | xxx-33      |      11 |            17 |       700 |   1 |
|    766 | xxx-74      |      32 |             1 |       300 |   1 |
+--------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should try this:

```
SELECT A.CDR_ID, A.TelephoneNo, A.Call_ID, A.call_Duration, A.Call_Plan
FROM YOUR_TABLE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration
            FROM YOUR_TABLE
            GROUP BY CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration
            HAVING COUNT(*)=1
            ) B ON A.CDR_ID= B.CDR_ID AND A.TelephoneNo=B.TelephoneNo AND A.Call_ID=B.Call_ID AND A.call_Duration=B.call_Duration
```

You can do a shorter query using Windows Function COUNT(*) OVER ...

Answer (score 0):

Below query will provide you the result

```
SELECT CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration,Call_Plan, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY CDR_ID,TelephoneNo,Call_ID,call_Duration,Call_Plan
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2;
```

It gives you with the count as well. If not required you can remove it.

Comment: Have changed, instead of lesser than, greater than is provided by mistake

Answer (score -3):

```
Select *, count(CDR_ID) 
from table
group by CDR_ID, TelephoneNo, Call_ID, call_Duration, Call_Plan
having count(CDR_ID) = 1
```